# Install dependencies error for cypress-realworld-app application

Tags: javascript, testing, cypress

I cloned the [cypress-realworld-app](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress-realworld-app), and I'm facing an error on the terminal during the `yarn install` command

```sh
"C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" C:\Users\Enamul\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\yarn\bin\yarn.js install
yarn install v1.22.17
[1/5] Validating package.json...
[2/5] Resolving packages...
warning Resolution field "@babel/compat-data@7.9.0" is incompatible with requested version "@babel/compat-data@^7.15.0"
warning Resolution field "@babel/compat-data@7.9.0" is incompatible with requested version "@babel/compat-data@^7.16.0"
warning Resolution field "@babel/compat-data@7.9.0" is incompatible with requested version "@babel/compat-data@^7.16.4"
warning Resolution field "@babel/compat-data@7.9.0" is incompatible with requested version "@babel/compat-data@^7.16.0"
warning Resolution field "@babel/compat-data@7.9.0" is incompatible with requested version "@babel/compat-data@^7.13.11"
warning Resolution field "@babel/compat-data@7.9.0" is incompatible with requested version "@babel/compat-data@^7.15.0"
warning Resolution field "@babel/compat-data@7.9.0" is incompatible with requested version "@babel/compat-data@^7.12.1"
warning Resolution field "@babel/compat-data@7.9.0" is incompatible with requested version "@babel/compat-data@^7.15.0"
warning Resolution field "@babel/compat-data@7.9.0" is incompatible with requested version "@babel/compat-data@^7.13.11"
[3/5] Fetching packages...
error graphql@16.2.0: The engine "node" is incompatible with this module. Expected version "^12.22.0 || ^14.16.0 || >=16.0.0". Got "14.15.0"
error Found incompatible module.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/install for documentation about this command.

Process finished with exit code 1
```

My Node Version `14.15.0`

Comment: Well, the error message says all: you need to upgrade your Node installation to a compatible version.

Comment: My current version node version is  `14.15.0` So how can I install `14.16.0` version?

Comment: [https://nodejs.org/dist/v14.16.0/](https://nodejs.org/dist/v14.16.0/) If for some reason you need to mantain v14.15.0 as well, use [Node Version Manager](https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows#node-version-manager-nvm-for-windows) (assuming you're on Windows)